# How to add the 3 days to the today date in azure cli script

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, backup

I have prepared azure cli script azurebk.azcli to take the backup of azure Virtual machine. The script execution environment is Linux. In the az-backup command I have mentioned the retention period in date format. But as per my client request I need to setup the crontab for this script. While executing the script normally without crontab, need to change the date everytime for retention period. Need help to get the azCLI command which will automatically pull the date (today date + add next 3days) for taking the backup.

Below is the code:

```
# Read the subscription ID or name
subscriptionId=subscriptionID
az account set --subscription $subscriptionId

# Check if required parameters are provided
if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <ResourceGroupName> <VMName>"
    exit 1
fi

# Assign RGName and VMName as argument parameters
resourceGroupName=$1
vmName=$2

#Define the parameters

date=(date -d "+3days")
recoveryServicesVaultName=testvault1
location=Central US

#Run the backup

az backup protection backup-now --resource-group $resourceGroupName --vault-name $recoveryServicesVaultName --container-name $vmName --item-name $vmName --retain-until $date --backup-management-type AzureIaasVM

# Check the exit status of the previous command
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "backup is successful"
    exit 0  # Success
else
    echo "backup is failed"
    exit 99  # Failure
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

> Need help to get the azCLI command which will automatically pull the date (today date + add next 3days) for taking the backup.

In order to calculate the retention date in `Azure CLI` script based on the current date and add `three days`. You can achieve this by using the `date` command in your script.

```
date=$(date -u +%d-%m-%Y -d "+3 days")
```

Here is the updated to code to initiate the backup of azure `Virtual Machine`.

```bash
    #!/bin/bash
    
   
    subscriptionId="Subscription_ID"
    az account set --subscription $subscriptionId
    
  
    if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
        echo "Usage: $0 venkat-RG venkat-linux"
        exit 1
    fi
    
    # Assign RGName and VMName as argument parameters
    resourceGroupName=$1
    vmName=$2
    
    # Fetch item_name for the VM
    itemname=$(az backup item list --resource-group $resourceGroupName --vault-name "vm-vault" --output json | jq -r --arg vmName "$vmName" '.[] | select(.properties.friendlyName == $vmName) | .name')
    
    # Check if itemname is empty
    if [ -z "$itemname" ]; then
        echo "VM not found in backup items."
        exit 1
    fi
    
    # Define the parameters
    date=$(date -u +%d-%m-%Y -d "+3 days") 
    echo "Retention Period: $date"
    
    recoveryServicesVaultName="vm-vault"
    location="East US"
    
    # Run the backup
    az backup protection backup-now --resource-group $resourceGroupName --item-name $itemname --vault-name $recoveryServicesVaultName --container-name $vmName --retain-until $date --backup-management-type AzureIaasVM
    
    # Check the exit status of the previous command
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Backup is successful"
        exit 0  # Success
    else
        echo "Backup failed"
        exit 99  # Failure
    fi
```

**Response:**

[image]

After running the code, backup job has been initiated as per date requirement in portal.

[image]